Poetry is not installing packages in Docker image
When running a container from the built image, Poetry does not install packages, although everything seems to be fine with it.
I set up Poetry, downloaded it, then installed the packages, but when the container starts, the terminal outputs that the packages are not installed.
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11.9

ENV POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=false \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python

RUN poetry self update

WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry install

FROM python:3.11.9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "bot.py"]


It looks like packages installed in the first stage are not available in the final build stage, I guess this is why your container cannot find them when it runs.

Your second FROM line creates a new pretty bare image. You could copy over stuff over from the first image, but you are doing that. So all that ends up in the new image is the app folder.

Yes as others have said, in your second stage you should copy the files you need from the first stage. -- Also in your second stage your CMD should likely be something like poetry run python bot.py otherwise the virtual environment (and the dependencies installed in it by Poetry) are completely and rightfully ignored. -- Some discussion around Poetry and Dockerfiles: https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/1879

Description
In the second stage of accessing the image, you need to copy the poetry installed in the previous image stage over. Like this:
# First Stage
FROM python:3.11.9-slim as base
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/.venv
# ...

# Second Stage
FROM base as runtime
COPY --from=base ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
# ...

But despite the above corrections, there are still many shortcomings. So I make the tutorial below.
Building Poetry Python Environment with Multi-stage Docker
I assume you are creating this container to build a Python development environment using Docker multistage with Poetry for managing Python packages. Therefore, I have included a development configuration that I believe meets the basic development needs.
Here is suggested project structure, the docker configuration and the usage of this environment for both development and production.
Project Structure
-- project
 |-- src
   |-- bot.py
 |-- docker-compose.yaml
 |-- Dockerfile
 |-- pyproject.toml
 |-- poetry.lock
 |-- .env

Docker Compose and Dockerfile
Here, Docker Compose is used to:

Easily create and integrate Docker containers (avoiding the need to repeatedly execute complex commands during development).
Conveniently integrate other microservices (such as databases or other endpoint services).
Easily mount shared spaces, reducing the time needed for dev image rebuilds.

docker-compose.yaml
services:
  dev-workspace:
    container_name: dev-workspace
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: dev
      args: 
        PROJECT_ROOT_DIR: ${CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}
    profiles:
      - dev
    volumes:
      - .:${CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}
      - dev-venv:${CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/.venv

  prod-workspace:
    container_name: prod-workspace
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: prod
      args: 
        PROJECT_ROOT_DIR: ${CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}
    profiles:
      - prod
    volumes:
      - .:${CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}
      - prod-venv:${CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/.venv

volumes:
  dev-venv:
  prod-venv:

Dockerfile
# Base Stage
## For basic environment and parameters
FROM python:3.11.9-slim as base

ARG PROJECT_ROOT_DIR 

ENV PROJECT_ROOT_DIR=${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR} \
    VIRTUAL_ENV=${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/.venv \
    POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache\
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1  

ENV PATH=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${POETRY_HOME}/bin:$PATH

# Builder Stage
## Install package dependencies and prepare for development

FROM base as builder

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.8.1 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl build-essential \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python \
    && python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry install

# Development
FROM builder as dev

ENV PROJECT_ENV=development

## Copy poetry and venv from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder ${POETRY_HOME} ${POETRY_HOME} 
COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}
COPY . ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}

# Production
FROM builder as prod

ENV PROJECT_ENV=production

## Only need to copy venv from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}
COPY . ${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}

CMD ["python", "bot.py"]

(For readers who might come across this post but are not yet familiar with how to use Poetry, here includes the default pyproject.toml and poetry.lock files.)
pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "playground"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A playground for python project experiment."
authors = ["liuyuweitarek <liuyuwei.tarek@gmail.com>"]
license = ""
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python="3.11.9"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "PyPI"
priority = "primary"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

poetry.lock
# This file is automatically @generated by Poetry 1.8.1 and should not be changed by hand.
package = []

[metadata]
lock-version = "2.0"
python-versions = "3.11.9"
content-hash = "13423705d4e2e1131e34e7ae158c2127fefcacc020eb9cda0bfb0893fdb89337"

.env
Environment variables are set here.
(Note that this is a simple demonstration and will only be used during local development. The docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile above will use the values from here. If you plan to use GitHub Actions or other CI/CD tools, make sure to protect your sensitive .env variables (e.g., API_KEY) and find a way for your CI/CD tool to read environment variables securely.)
Here it is:
CONTAINER_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR=/project

Usage
Build up Image & Run Container
# First build or Rebuild
$ docker compose --profile [dev, prod] up --build -d

# After first build, unless modifying Dockerfile, you can just run the image with
$ docker compose --profile [dev, prod] up -d


--profile [dev, prod]: Choose dev or prod. Defined in docker-compose.yaml specified which service to run, which is also the same as --target dev in docker build
--build: build up the image.
-d: run in the background.

Attach to Container terminal
$ docker exec -it [dev-workspace, prod-workspace] /bin/bash

Close Container
$ docker composee --profile [dev, prod] down

In the development container

Check which Python env are used
root@c55da529c658:/project$ which python

# OUTPUT
/project/.venv/bin/python


Add packages to the development, production environment
# For development
root@c55da529c658:/project$ poetry add --group dev black

# For production
root@c55da529c658:/project$ poetry add --group prod fastapi


Remove packages from the development, production environment
# For development
root@c55da529c658:/project$ poetry remove --group dev black

# For production
root@c55da529c658:/project$ poetry remove --group prod fastapi



Further usage, please see more details in Poetry Docs.
Persistent Virtual Environment with Bind Mount: Faster Rebuilds and Retained Dependencies
Using a bind mount in docker-compose.yaml for the .venv directory allows you to persist your virtual environment across container rebuilds. This setup ensures while your source code and configuration files are synchronized between the local machine and container, the virtual environment remains isolated and persistent within the container, leveraging Docker volumes.
Here is where it defined:
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  dev-workspace:
    ...
    volumes: dev-venv:{PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/.venv

volumes:
    - dev-venv

When you launch container, here is how the configuration above affect the mount of .venv look like:
On Local Machine Terminal*
-- project
 |-- src
   |-- bot.py
 |-- docker-compose.yaml
 |-- Dockerfile
 |-- pyproject.toml
 |-- poetry.lock
 |-- .env
 |-- .venv
   |-- (Empty here!)

On Container Terminal
-- project
 |-- src
   |-- bot.py
 |-- docker-compose.yaml
 |-- Dockerfile
 |-- pyproject.toml
 |-- poetry.lock
 |-- .env
 |-- .venv (Fully needed packages)
   |-- bin
   |-- lib
   |-- include
   |-- lib64
   |-- pyvenv.cfg

This setup ensures that installed Python packages are retained, saving time by avoiding the need to reinstall dependencies during development.

Your Dockerfile fails. I've got  > [builder 5/5] RUN poetry install: 0.141 /bin/sh: 1: poetry: not found once tried to build it.

Hello, thank you for your reply. May I ask if you have recreated the same "directory structure" and "copied all the files"? If you have done both, you might need to check whether the PATH in your current stage (I'm assuming you are using dev) contains "/opt/poetry/bin". In the Docker file, before running poetry install, add RUN echo $PATH to confirm the setup.

Additionally, after answering this question, I did more research and found that the approach in this answer is overly complicated, and the image is too large. Therefore, I simplified it and created this template. You can follow the instructions in the README.md to try it out. If you encounter any issues, feel free to submit a PR. Thank you!
